# NSInternalInconsistencyException in Cocos-2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to follow a tutorial from a book on how to program with Cocos 2d, but when I try to run the program, it compiles fine, but it hangs at the loading screen. This error came up in the debug screen:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e5a012 0x1a3be7e 0x1e59e78 0x44d665 0x36f7c 0x3190 0x2c7a 0x36665 0x2a32 0x25be 0x97e1af 0x97e7a1 0x97f94b 0x990cb5 0x991beb 0x983698 0x297ddf9 0x297dad0 0x1dcfbf5 0x1dcf962 0x1e00bb6 0x1dfff44 0x1dffe1b 0x97f17a 0x980ffc 0x2111 0x2055)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Here is a screenshot of the file (main.m, which I did not touch):[image]

It was working fine when before I added a few changes the book told me to do. I have not touched main.m, and I dont see why it doesn't work.
Any help?

Thanks LearnCocos2d, I fixed the first one, in my code, I spelled the image name Spider.png, where the file is spider.png

But, now it shows a different error, any idea on how to fix?
2013-08-27 17:59:31.695 DoodleDrop[7557:c07] init: 
DoodleDrop(7557,0xacd02a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)**
 error: can't allocate region
 **set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
error: _regexp-down [n]
2013-08-27 17:59:44.415 DoodleDrop[7557:c07]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: ' **-[NSObject allocWithZone:]: attempt to allocate object of class 'CCSprite' failed'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e5a012 0x1a3be7e 0x1ee51a4 0x1a4fa6b 0x1a4fa55 0x56747 0x316e 0x2c8a 0x36675 0x2a42 0x25ce 0x97e1af 0x97e7a1 0x97f94b 0x990cb5 0x991beb 0x983698 0x297ddf9 0x297dad0 0x1dcfbf5 0x1dcf962 0x1e00bb6 0x1dfff44 0x1dffe1b 0x97f17a 0x980ffc 0x2121 0x2065)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

The other error I got from the breakpoint said it couldn't load a sprite, this one isn't s clear to me.

Comment: add an exception breakpoint in Xcode, then you'll see the (nearest) line of code causing the exception -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

i just meet similar problem in Sprite kit, i solved it by 1/2 the size of my image.